# Module not found in Electron / Atom Shell

Tags: javascript, node.js, requirejs, npm, electron

I'm new to npm, node and Electron.

My Folder looks like:

```
-package.json
-index.html
-main.js
-js/myStuff.js
-node_modules
```

In the file `myStuff.js`I have `var chokidar = require('chokidar');` but it shows then `module not found` error.

In the `index.html` I included the `myFile.js` like normaly in a script tag.

I did read how node is looking for modules. But that doesn't help cause then it should find it, cause it's looks in all parent dirs for the node_modules folder and then in there for a chokidar folder and in that for the index.js file, which is there.

What am I doing wrong?

***It works now, but i have no idea why..***

Comment: Did you run `npm install chokidar --save`?

Comment: @RomanDibikhin yes, and i read, that this adds it also to the package.json, which i checked and it's there listed in `dependencies`. I played around and could get it like `require('./node_modules/chokidar')` but that cant be the correct way of doing this..

Comment: Show your `main.js`, please. Which file do you run and how?

Comment: @RomanDibikhin My `main.js` is exactly the same like in the quickstart of electron described. Everything is the same execpt that i added `myFile.js` and included it with the `<script src="">` tag in the `index.html`

Comment: Do you call `myFile.js` and `myStuff.js` the same file?

Comment: @RomanDibikhin sry i meant `myStuff.js` it's the only single fily i added after the quickstart and added it in the `index.html` then i installed chokidar and required it in `myStuff.js`. I almost changed nothing.

Comment: @RomanDibikhin very strange it works now but i have no idea why.. but anyhow cause you tried to help.. i would accept you answer wathever it would contain :S

Comment: No problem. Hope you'll get it done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In contrast to other node apps, electron doesn't automatically set your `NODE_PATH` to global (i.e. `/usr/bin`) or local (e.g. `node_modules`) [folders](https://docs.npmjs.com/files/folders). So you need to export it manually:

```
NODE_PATH=/path/to/node_modules electron my_app
```

Comment: @user2834172 then i suggest to write it in your question for the next person!

Comment: @user2834172 try to reproduce the problem and find out thr concrete problem/solution. This would massively help the others.